# Desired trajectory generation from transfer function in control theory

Tags: transfer-function, control-systems

I am trying to implement the backstepping techniques for quadrotor described in this article : [Backstepping control for a quadrotor helicopter: Madani & Benallegue 2006](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/224685297_Backstepping_Control_for_a_Quadrotor_Helicopter)

Since I am new to the control theory (and I know that my question concerns the most easiest part of this paper), I don't understand how can I generate my desired trajectory from the transfer function they provide at equation (56)

$$
H(s) = \frac{1}{(s+1)^6}
$$

Or, generally speaking, how can I link any kind of trajectory to its corresponding transfer function ?
Did my question make sense ? Is there a confusion ?
I mostly ask to the community some relevant documentations (and not technical answer in this particular case).

I did some "exercises" on controlling cart trajectory for instance but the trajectory equation was always provided: circular, van der pol cycle. There were no transfer functions.

Comment: Look up the 'internal model principle' in control theory. You can represent classes of signals as transfer-functions; most famously any step can be modelled using 1/s and embedding this model in the control law enables the control law to track any step (given some reasonable assumptions); the same goes for other signal models